# How do I save the name of a MATLAB file from a list?

Tags: matlab, matrix, save

I am currently working with a script that saves matrices as .mat files from other .mat files. I need to save 96 separate files so I have a loop that goes through the matrix names. I need to have the matrices saved with specific titles, that I have saved the titles in cell arrays {}. However, when I use the save(filename,variable) function, I get an error saying:

*Error using save
Must be a text scalar.
Error in File_Creator (line 35)
save(name,fname);*

My matrices need to be named 'PHI_Af','PHI_Am' (so on until) 'SLR_EF' (so every cr value needs to have a matrix with every par value. Here is what I am currently attempting:

```
cr = {'Af','Am','As','Aw','BS','BW','Cs','Cw','Cf','Ds','Dw','Df','ET','EF'};
par = {'PHI','BLD','KS','LAMBDA','PSIS','SLR'};
underscore = {'_'};

%% i and j are parameters in a loop where i = 1:length(par) and j = 1:length(cr)
%% f is the variable currently storing the matrix

s.(horzcat(par{i},underscore{1},cr{j})) = f;
name = string(strcat(par{i},'_',cr{j},'.mat'));
fname = string(s.(horzcat(par{i},underscore{1},cr{j})));
        
save(name,fname);
```

When I replace 'fname' with a generic string e.g. 'f', then the command runs but all the matrices save as the same thing ('f'), which makes it extremely difficult to run them all in the same script later.

I hope somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong or provide me with a better solution. Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Thank you

Comment: Don’t use the function `string`, you are working with char arrays, don’t mix those with strings. Strings are created with `"` quotes, char arrays with `'` quotes.

Comment: I’m still confused by what you’re actually trying to save. The same command is `save(file_name,var_name,var_name,...)`. So you need to pass the *name* of the variables you want to save. And the first argument must be the name of the file.

Comment: You seem to trying to use a struct though. Maybe you want the `save(fname, '-struct',structName)` syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the matrix, f, changes in each iteration of the loop (due to some other code you didn't post), it seems like this is all the code you need:

```
cr = {'Af','Am','As','Aw','BS','BW','Cs','Cw','Cf','Ds','Dw','Df','ET','EF'};
par = {'PHI','BLD','KS','LAMBDA','PSIS','SLR'};

for i = 1:length(par)
    for j = 1:length(cr)
        % add code here that loads the matrix f
        name = [par{i}, '_', cr{j}, '.mat'];        
        save(name, 'f');
    end
end
```